# What would be the meaning of this ER Diagram and why?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

If no other indication is given, what would be the meaning of this ER Diagram?

(a) An Artist may record (0 or more) songs.

(b) An Artist may record (1 or more) songs.

[image]

Comment: Artist and Song are entity tables, Recorded is a junction table, and the ovals represent elements or columns in the tables.  There is no row in the Recorded table unless an Artist recorded a Song.

Comment: This ER-Diagram is incomplete if it is a reflection of real world. A person is seen as an artist as well as a band is. This would provide a Partitioning. Person and Band would be Artist subtypes. Ah... Also, a song may be composed by more than one person. The "Author" property/attribute in Song is incorrect, and this should be a relationship between Person and Song. In a conceptual model, how would you relate it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Reading from left-to-right, an artist may record 0 or more songs.  Reading from right-to-left, a song may be recorded by 1 or more artists.

Comment: Curious.  I read it as "An artist must have recorded at least one song" and "Songs may not be recorded".  Meaning an artist may record 1 or more songs, but not zero (for then he's not an artist).

Comment: Getting feedback from one of my role models is always a pleasure.  So of course, I had to double-check my statement.  I believe my reading follows Chen's notation from his paper `The Entity-Relationship Model - Towards a Unified Understanding of Data` section 3, pages 19-20.  What the author of the diagram intended remains an open question.

Comment: Erwin, did you mean "Songs may be not recorded"? rather than "songs may not be recorded"?

Comment: Yes.  Songs may be not recorded.  My remark was more to point out that the semantics of this particular ER language dialect are apparently not as self-evident as they might be, rather than to claim correctness of my interpretation.

Comment: (Though I do still find it an odd idea that someone can be an artist without having recorded any song, and a song cannot be a song unless and until it has been recorded by some artist.)

Comment: Agreed, the model doesn't match our common-sense understanding, but it sounds about right for the recording industry.  "Artists" can sign up with a label before recording any music, while only songs recorded by signed artists are monetizable and of interest.

Comment: Ah yes.  One has to be careful to make the proper choices when deciding from where to take a perspective.  Baie belangrik :-)